# Using a positional parameter as the name of the array I want to loop over

Tags: bash

I have been looking at other similar questions but didn't find the proper answer. `$1` is the name of the array i want to loop over.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in ${"$1"[@]}

do

echo "$i"

done
```

Comment: How do you call this script?

Comment: @n7rc : `$1` is always a scalar. There is no way that you can invoke a script in a way that this parameter becomes an array. `$@` would be (kind of) an array, but as a special variable, it does not act like an array in **every** respect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I don't misunderstand your not very well written question, you are looking for [bash indirection](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver2.html#EX78), which is available since `bash, version 2`.

Below a minimal example

```
#! /bin/bash

foo=( 1 2 3 4 )
bar=( 5 6 7 8 )


if [[ ( "$1" -ne foo && "$1" -ne bar ) ]];
then 
    echo "Usage: $0 <foo|bar>"
    exit 1
fi

ambito="$1"[@]           # here what you are looking for

for i in "${!ambito}";   # here the indirection
do
    echo -n "$i "
done
echo ""
```

And you can call this `indirection.sh` scrit as:

```
$ ./indirection.sh  foo
1 2 3 4
```

or

```
$ ./indirection.sh  bar
5 6 7 8
```

This being said, using indirection may cause confusion. In most cases it could be replaced by associative arrays.

Comment: Thank you. That was the solution.

Comment: @n7rc You are welcome. I modified my answer, with a more detailed script and a link to documentation. Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

`$1` is the first command line argument, not all of them. Probably what you are looking for is `$@`.

And to create an array holding them, something like:

```sh
ambito=($@)
```

Comment: No, it is precisely about passing the first argument of the command line that corresponds to one of the arrays contained in hosts.sh. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: well then the solution to your problem depends on what you mean by "corresponds".

Comment: if `$1` holds the name of the array, you can write a switch statement

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ask below what is my intention.